# How do I call stargazer on a list of models?

Tags: r, do.call, stargazer

I just ran a series of models in a nice, flexible way that enforced data-code separation.  I had a nice list of formulas and models in my configuration section which I `lapply`'d over to get a list of model objects.  Now I want to display them in `stargazer`, but it doesn't take a list object.  How do I do this without having to type out each list element?

Reproducible example:

```
require(stargazer)
l <- list()
l$lm1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning + raises + critical,
data=attitude)
l$lm2 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning, data=attitude)
## create an indicator dependent variable, and run a probit model
attitude$high.rating <- (attitude$rating > 70)
l$prbt <- glm(high.rating ~ learning + critical + advance, data=attitude,
family = binomial(link = "probit"))
stargazer( l[[1]], l[[2]], l[[3]], title="Results", align=TRUE, type="text")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please make sure you are using an up-to-date version of the package. Starting with version 4.5.3 (available on CRAN since Nov 2013), `stargazer` has been able to accept lists of object in exactly the way you would expect:

`stargazer(l, title="Results", align=TRUE, type="text")`

Answer (score 4):

Use `do.call`:

```
do.call( stargazer, l )
```

However, this precludes passing in arguments in the usual way:

```
> do.call( stargazer, l, type="text" )
Error in do.call(stargazer, l, type = "text") : 
  unused argument (type = "text")
```

Therefore, you have to add the named arguments to the list:

```
l$type <- "text"
l$align <- TRUE
l$title <- "Results"
do.call( stargazer, l )
```

Another way to do this is to curry the stargazer function:

```
require(functional)
sgCurried <- Curry( stargazer, type="text" ) # all arguments to stargazer go in here
do.call( sgCurried, l )
```